# Scala Remote Actors - Pitfalls

Tags: scala, network-programming, scala-2.8, actor, remote-actors

While writing Scala RemoteActor code, I noticed some pitfalls:

- RemoteActor.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader()  has to be set in order to avoid "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
- link doesn't always work due to "a race condition for which a NetKernel (the facility responsible for forwarding messages remotely) that backs a remote actor can close before the remote actor's proxy (more specifically, proxy delegate) has had a chance to send a message remotely indicating the local exit." (Stephan Tu)
- RemoteActor.select doesn't always return the same delegate ([RemoteActor.select - result deterministic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301236/remoteactor-select-result-deterministic))
- Sending a delegate over the network prevents the application to quit normally ([RemoteActor unregister actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264210/remoteactor-unregister-actor))
- Remote Actors won't terminate if RemoteActor.alive() and RemoteActor.register() are used outside act. (See the answer of Magnus)

Are there any other pitfalls a programmer should be aware of?

Comment: I'm currently up against the "RemoteActor.classLoader = ..." pitfall, but even though I need this line *somewhere*, I can't work out where! Can anyone point to an explanation of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another; you need to put your RemoteActor.alive() and RemoteActor.register() calls inside your act method when you define your actor or the actor won't terminate when you call exit(); see [How do I kill a RemoteActor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330096/how-do-i-kill-a-remoteactor/3330222#3330222)